# Docker Postgres:9.4 , como criar schema no banco assim que o container iniciar?

Tags: docker

Olá, tudo tranquilo pessoal ?

Estou mexendo com o docker-compose configurando um sistema com docker estou mapeando volumes com arquivos *.sh no diretorio `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`para iniciar as configurações básicas do meu banco:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports: 
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 'imn'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'intelbras'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'intelbras'
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

dentro da pasta init eu tenho um script *.sh rodando para criar o schema

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE SCHEMA imn AUTHORIZATION intelbras
EOSQL
```

quando uso o comando

> docker-compose up

ele sobe o banco porém não cria o schema alguém poderia me dizer aonde estou  fazendo de errando ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja um ';' faltando no final da linha do SQL, logo depois do '...AUTHORIZATION intelbras'. O Banco fica esperando o fim da instrução. e não executa, testei aqui e funcionou.

Comment: Tbm tinha pensado nisso, mas descobri que estava mapeando uma diretório que não tinha arquivo continha nada, coloquei o arquivo *.sh dentro do diretório e funcionou, obrigado pela resposta :)